# Bash script to extract first seconds and rename mp3 files in folder

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, mp3, sox

I have a folder with several MP3 files that I need to extract 10-15 seconds of audio from. I would also like to rename these by appending sample-(name).mp3 to the converted files.  How can I do this via Shell Script?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't be done just with the shell; you need a command-line audio tool to extract the clip.

Comment: Oh, probably should have clarified, have ffmpeg, sox and mp3splt --

Comment: use bash script and ffmpeg has trim like function.

Answer (score 2):

You need a tool like ffmpeg to accomplish this. There are other tools like mp3split as well.

You can script something like this.

for each infile in the directory:

ffmpeg -t 15 -i infile.mp3 -acodec copy sample-$infile.mp3

Comment: Any way to use variables or wildcards or will I have to specify each infile name?

Comment: $ for infile in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -t 15 -i $infile -acodec copy sample-$infile; done

Comment: comes back: -acodec: No such file or directory
removing -acodec: copy:  No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Hu, I don't now how you can extract exactaly 10/15 seconds of your file(.mp3), but you can use the program named xxd in order to read a part of the file in hexadecimal format and copy this in a new file named sample_name...
try to write a little script and i try to help you.

Comment: tape man xxd, and you have many examples, try to use xxd with option in comand line and after paste it into a bash scipt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a user on Linux pages - got this bash script, works perfectly. Thanks to everyone for helping me with this, greatly appreciated!

```
#/bin/bash
```

for i in *.mp3
do 
  mp3splt "$i" 00.00.00 00.10.00 -o sample-"${i%.mp3}"
done

Comment: make sure you mark this question as answered, then.